# Can't connect remotely to my Neo4j database

Tags: neo4j, remote-access

I have a Neo4j database on my desktop computer that I would like to access remotely. I'm not very knowledgeable about servers/networking, but here's a list of things I've done to try to get it working:

- Uncommented the `dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0` line in the settings, as well as `dbms.connector.http.listen_address=:7474` and `dbms.connector.https.listen_address=:7473`
- Set up a TCP/UDP port forward on my router mapping 30408 to 7473.
- Reserved a static IP for my desktop (the same one that appears in the port forward).
- Defined incoming firewall exceptions on my desktop for ports 7474, 7473, and 30408 for both TCP and UDP (I'm guessing the 30408 one doesn't matter, but I've been trying everything).

When I try to connect through Chrome with {public_ip}:30408, it gives ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE (Firefox just says "The connection was reset").

I *am* able to successfully connect to the neo4j browser on my local network with {local_ip}:7474.

Edit: Should I look into trying to do this with SSH? I still don't know what is going wrong in the first place.